# Start Brightcove video onclick

Tags: brightcove

The following code loads the video when clicking on a link but how can I get the video to actual play when clicking instead?

```
<a class="test" onClick="BCL.addPlayer('video_player', '2102405248001');" href="#">Test</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [API for the VideoPlayer module](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/reference/symbols/brightcove.api.modules.VideoPlayerModule.html). Have a look at the play() method. When  onTemplateLoaded() is triggered, you can call Play(). Conversely, you may be able to set the video to autoStart.  Check here for [player config params](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/player-configuration-parameters).